# TypeError: Qt.ConnectionType expected, not 'Ui_Quiz'

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pyqt, click

I am triying to create personality prediction system with ML and GUI here is the last error I get and I couldn't figure out what the problem is. That is about "connect" I assume but I am not supposed to delete it.

```
class Ui_Quiz(object):
    def setupUi(self, Quiz):
        Quiz.setObjectName("Quiz")
        Quiz.resize(1082, 832)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Quiz)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 951, 711))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(211, 255, 164);\n"
"")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 70, 221, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 75 18pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 600, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(64, 103, 42);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 150, 741, 421))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(135, 177, 100);\n"
"border-radius: 12px")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 51, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 70, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.text = 0
        self.age = int(self.lineEdit.text)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 71, 21))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 190, 91, 21))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 250, 101, 21))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 70, 151, 21))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 130, 131, 21))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 190, 101, 21))
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.text = 0
        self.gender = int(self.lineEdit_2.text)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_3.text = 0
        self.openness = int(self.lineEdit_3.text)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 250, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_4.text = 0
        self.neuroticism = int(self.lineEdit_4.text)

        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 70, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.lineEdit_5.text = 0
        self.conscientiousness = int(self.lineEdit_5.text)

        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 130, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.lineEdit_6.text = 0
        self.agreeableness = int(self.lineEdit_6.text)

        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 190, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 240, 181);")
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.lineEdit_7.text = 0
        self.extraversion = int(self.lineEdit_7.text)


        self.retranslateUi(Quiz)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Quiz)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self,prediction(self.gender, self.age, self.openness ,self.neuroticism, self.conscientiousness, self.agreeableness, self.extraversion))
```

TypeError: Qt.ConnectionType expected, not 'Ui_Quiz' this the error

- Last line causes error I wanted to show the whole code to be more clear*

Comment: Your example is not clear, because it does not show all of the ***relevant*** code. The contents of the `Ui_Quiz` class has no relevance at all here, because it is automatically generated by the pyuic tool, *and must never be edited manually*. See [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) in the PyQt5 docs for how to do things properly. Please also complete a [PyQt5 tutorial](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) to the learn the basics of how to use signals and slots correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self,prediction(self.gender, self.age, self.openness ,self.neuroticism, self.conscientiousness, self.agreeableness, self.extraversion))
```

the self here as a argument is the problem, probably. you need to remove it, if it is typo. may be it has to be self.prediction, you got to know this.

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.prediction(self.gender, self.age, self.openness ,self.neuroticism, self.conscientiousness, self.agreeableness, self.extraversion))
```

or

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(prediction(self.gender, self.age, self.openness ,self.neuroticism, self.conscientiousness, self.agreeableness, self.extraversion))
```

Comment: None of your examples will work, and will just raise more exceptions (i.e. `TypeError` and `NameError`). There are much more fundamental problems with the OPs code than the simple typo.

Comment: You are right...